# Drools LHS Evaluation: matches vs String.contains()

Tags: drools

I've been reading through the docs, but can't seem to find an answer to the following.  I need a Drools rule to check and see whether or not a string contains another string.  I was wondering what the difference (if any) in evaluation would be in writing it like this:

```
rule "String Matches"
   when
      Address(street matches ".*apt.*")
   then
      log.info("Someone likely lives in an apartment");
end
```

versus writing the same logic like this:

```
rule "String Contains"
   when
      Address(street.contains("apt"))
   then
      log.info("Someone likely lives in an apartment");
end
```

Is there any difference between how the rules engine will evaluate the two in terms of safety, optimization, or performance?

*And I'm aware that the example above is not a great way to check for apartments in addresses, was just a simple example off the top of my head using a concept with which most folks are familiar.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is about the same as using `String.matches( Regex regex )` versus `String.contains( CharSequence charSeq )` in Java. Regular expressions need to be compiled and interpreted when evaluated against a CharSequence; looking for a substring in a string matching the given string requires less effort.

And it's quite easy to write an inefficient regular expression. `".*apt.*"` will be executed by matching all of the target string's characters to `.*`, then the RE engine will backup, try again, and so on, until the last occurrence of `apt` is matched. Much better is `".*?apt.*"`, which will continue to match after the leftmost `apt` is detected.

Safety? From what?